# is there a way to get the non-modified date and time in java?

Tags: java, windows, rcp

Suppose I change the system date and time. When I use `Date` or `Calendar` objects in Java, I get the changed/modified time which is not correct.

I need the exact local time, not the modified time.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");         
Date date = new Date(millis);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Then don't modify the time.

Comment: Download it from a server as done in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081262/getting-time-from-public-time-server-using-timetcpclient

Comment: @FrancescoSerra, this works fine with specific servers. i think servers should support NTP to get the above code working.
Whereas i have a server, gave that id but i'm not getting anything in return.
What should i do to get time from my server ?

Comment: @Sudeep I don't know how your server is done! I think you have to implement a service on your server and then consume it from your java application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you could query some remote server/service to get the correct time and then convert it to your local zone (if needed).

But since `System.currentTimeMillis()` uses the system's date and time, what you get when using this piece of code is correct according to the [specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()). Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596259/how-does-system-currenttimemillis-get-its-time) for a more detailed explanation on how it works internally.