# by changing date from system we can break time expiration limit

Tags: java, jsp, date

We have a web_app  (in java) and we'll be giving access client that is based on **credit and time limit**.

In client machine change system time then also application is run still.

The requirement is that how to check time and date with internet time?

I have client IP

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an Internet time server to get the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your server clock as the source for official time.  You can start when you get the first client request