# Determine the internet time of another country in Java

Tags: java, time, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

I am developing a Java application that will be used by people from around the world. One feature requires it to display the current time in Melbourne, Australia.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time) answer and adapted the code as follows, but it returns my current time (as expected). It uses the [Apache Commons Net library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/):

```
    try {
        String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";   
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
        return new Date(returnTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

**How can I modify this code to return the time in Melbourne, rather than my time? I am open to other solutions to solve this problem as well.**

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Taking Jon's advice, I have used the [JodaTime library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and built the following code to solve the problem. It can be used for other time zones by changing Australia/Melbourne to [any timezone found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
    try {
        //Get the time for the current time zone.
        String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";   
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();

        //Format it to the Melbourne TimeZone.
        DateTimeZone tzMelbourne = DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Melbourne");
        return new DateTime(returnTime).toDateTime(tzMelbourne);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently returning a `java.util.Date` - that doesn't *have* a time zone. It's just an instant in time. It's not in your time zone, or some other time zone - it's just an instant. When you call `toString()`, that will give you a textual representation in your local time zone, but that's not part of the data in the object.

If you need to represent "a date/time in a particular time zone" then you should use the `Calendar` class, or ideally use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) which is a *much* better date/time API.

Alternatively, if you're just trying to *format* the date/time in a particular time zone, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` - set the time zone, and then format the `Date` value you're already returning.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking up from an NTP server, you can use `java.util.TimeZone`to get time of a specific place in the world.(It also knows about day-light savings)
Your timezone ID is 'Australia/Melbourne'.

```
TimeZone australiaMelbourneTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne");

Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

//Use this Calendar instance to print time
```

Not: I have found the Timezone ID `Australia/Melbourne` by dumping all avaliable time zone IDs supported by the java.util.TimeZone as follows:

```
   for(String timeZoneID: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
            System.out.println(timeZoneID);
   }
```

The output included 'Australia/Melbourne' as follows:

...
Australia/Brisbane
Australia/Canberra
Australia/Currie
Australia/Hobart
Australia/Lindeman
**Australia/Melbourne**
Australia/NSW
Australia/Queensland
Australia/Sydney
Australia/Tasmania

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html). You can get a calendar instance and change its timezone.