# How to get seconds since epoch without connection with device time?

Tags: android, utc

I know about such method:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
```

which return seconds since epoch. BUT it depends on time on device. Maybe smb know about getting timestamp without connection with device time? For example when I change time at device/emulator the total number of seconds since epoch changes too, and logic of my program crashes.

Comment: `and logic of my program crashes.` if your app stability relies on the epoch then I highly recommend you fix that first...

Comment: @ZUNJAE, what do you think about ntp server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an Internet time server to get the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time). And/or of [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get internet time instead of device time use [truetime](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android)

PS: it was little slow for me to connect, but did work

Comment: I have already found this library but I can't use it due to difficulties with using at my project ;(