# Using ntp to get internet time server

Tags: java, ntp

I am trying to get time from internet using ntp on Net-beans IDE 8.2. I am not getting error but the program keeps running without displaying the time.

I have already added the commons-net-3.6.jar in library. Am I missing something?

Please have a look at my code below. I have taken this code from: [How to use an Internet time server to get the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time)

```
package timelookup;
import java.util.Date;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;

public class TimeLookup {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
       String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";   
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
        Date time = new Date(returnTime);
        System.out.println("Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + time);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what happens when you get to the `println` line?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nothing is displayed

Comment: That makes no sense. If you have no exception thrown, then when you run this program, at the very least you should get an output that starts with "Time from" - even if there is no value. Are you sure your program actually terminates and doesn't get stuck in one of the network calls?

Comment: in fact the program keeps running and does not terminate.

Comment: So use a debugger, check where it gets stuck, and check the documentation for that call to see how to prevent it from getting stuck. My assumption would be that you have a networking issue.

Comment: ok, thank you, i will try