# Extract UTC time with jsoup by id

Tags: java, html, date, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract the Current Unix epoch time in milliseconds from this [website](https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html) but I failed. Here is my code

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html").get();
String content = document.getElementById("epochMs").text();
```

[image]

For some reason, the content is empty. Maybe I need to click on the href link first to stop the running timer? Any idea how to get the timestamp?

Comment: Why would you do that rather than get it directly via code?

Comment: Because i have many nodes and i want to synchronize them for example someone in greece someone in germany thats why and clocks of machines maybe differ

Comment: Even if that's the case, scraping a site is way inferior to making a request to a time server directly

Comment: i just want to synchronize the whole clients and this is the easiest way that i find. if you have something else on your mind please feel free to post it in comment

Comment: Have a look at time.google.com. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time)

Comment: i am still having issues i use NTPUDPClient and still get inconsistencies between different machines cant to synchronize them any help timestamp is different

Comment: Are you using the `long` value?

Comment: long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();

Comment: Of what nature are the "inconsistencies"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251652/discussion-between-mixalis-navridis-and-g00se).