# Why does the time differ by a few seconds on each android device?

Tags: android, time

I found that the second hand of each Android phone has a certain difference. Sometimes the difference is a few seconds, and sometimes the difference is more than ten seconds. I want to know why this is?

i don't know what can i do.

Comment: You don't mention if the devices have SIMs or not, or tried to resync the time as described in [How to force a time/date update in my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114644/3573) See: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time-source

Answer (score 1):

if you need absolutely sync the time, you can try some ntp service.

you can reference this post for get the ntp time in java.

See [*How to use an Internet time server to get the time?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4442192/642706)